# Range queries using B trees and B+-trees

Tags: c++, tree, b-tree

I am writing a program to retrieve the number of objects within a given range and I am using the B-tree data structure to implement my solution as the number of objects cannot fit in RAM. I came across several articles saying that B+ trees are far superior than B trees for range queries and are used by all major database implementations. I was unable to understand why B+ trees are superior than B trees as all the data are stored on the leaf and it will take h (height of tree) disk accesses to retrieve the node and perform the range query while in the B tree the interval may be located on parent nodes and the disk accesses would be thus minimized. Furthermore, if I have a query such as return # of objects of a particular key then I may be able to locate the key before descending all the way down to the leaves as in B+ trees. Why then do they say that B+-trees are efficient than B-trees for range queries? If I have to write a program to perform range queries shouldn't B trees be the right data structure? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 6):

Practical B tree and B+ tree implementations tend to have nodes of a fixed byte size that is chosen to match the page size of the architecture or another fixture like the cluster size on disk. A typical value would be 4096 bytes.

A B+ tree can fit lots more keys into an internal node because there is no space needed for the record data. That gives higher fanout (lower tree height) and better cache utilisation, since a given set of index pages (internal nodes) 'covers' more queries than would be the case for a B tree.

A second advantage of B+ trees is that the keys in internal nodes are only needed for routing searches to the right leaf. They only need to separate the things on their left from the things on their right but they do not have to correspond to any actual record keys. This means that they can often be shortened, and it also means that deletions do not have to be propagated from the leaf layer into the index layer (i.e., once you have a deleted a key from a leaf, you're done - no need to delete anything from internal nodes except for what happens naturally during rebalancings).

Also, in a typical B+ tree the leaf nodes have pointers to their left and right siblings. This means that you can iterate over a range of records by walking a linked list of pages, instead of having to use the tricky iteration logic typical for B trees.

> in the B tree the interval may be located on parent nodes and the disk accesses would be thus minimized

To lay that theory to rest, estimate how many keys total are located in internal nodes of a B tree and how many keys total are located in leaf nodes. That ratio tells you how often a search can stop early, before descending all the way to the leaf level. Note: the early-out scenario is only applicable to queries where the *exact* key happens to be present in the tree; otherwise a descent to the leaf level is inevitable.